# verilog loop with define macro

Tags: verilog

I'm working on my first Verilog codes: I defined some define macros `ADDR1,`ADDR2, `ADDR3 ... the number of these define macros is different for each project. In my code I wrote a loop as:

```
for (i=0; i<num_of_macros;i++) begin
   `ADDR1 = 0;
   `ADDR2 = 0;
   ... (according to the macros number)
end
```

I'm trying now to write a generic loop. My question is: there is a possibility to write the macros depended on i? Like ADDR%i, or something like that? 
Thanks and have a good day
Juliette

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't store value of macro run time, but for your fixed requirement, we can do it like below,

```
`define ADDR(i) i

module tb;

integer j;
initial
begin
  for (j=0;j<10;j=j+1)
  begin
    $display("%d", `ADDR(j));
  end
end
endmodule


Result:

# Loading work.tb(fast)
# run -all
#           0
#           1
#           2
#           3
#           4
#           5
#           6
#           7
#           8
#           9
#  quit -f
```

So you can use ADDR(1), instead of ADDR1.